# Using mod_rewrite to accept several DirectoryIndex variants

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How to redirect it as follows?:

mysite.com -> mysite.com/index.php

mysite.com/index.php -> mysite.com/index.php

mysite.com/index -> mysite.com/index.php

mysite.com/main.php -> mysite.com/index.php

mysite.com/main -> mysite.com/index.php

Same with .html extension (ie. mysite.com/index.html -> mysite.com/index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php
RewriteRule ^/(main|index)(\.(php|html))?$ /index.php
```

If you want to use these rules in the .htaccess file in the document root directory, remove the leading slash from the patterns.